# What's the most effective way to deal with a big group of sentries?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm playing Capture the Flag (on Turbine), and the enemy's team has a group of about five level-3 sentries right outside the door to our base. I've tried being a Soldier, Heavy and Demoman, and destroying them, but all five gun me down before I have the chance. The Scout's essentially useless and he'll be destroyed almost instantly, as will the Pyro and Medic. As a Spy, I am either blown up by grenades or sticky bombs before I even get near the sentries, or, if I'm lucky enough to get to them, as soon as I sap them, another Engineer comes along and removes my sapper (and I obvious can't backstab him as other Sentries will quickly shoot at me).

What is the best thing to do in this situation (in order to destroy lots of sentries), where coming into contact with them is inevitable (What is an ideal class to use, and what is the best strategy)?

Comment: Where specifically "outside the door"? The big one on floor level? How far from it?

Comment: @Kappei CTF (and 5CP) maps in TF2 are general denoted as being split into RED base, neutral area, and BLU base.  In Turbine, the center warehouse is the only neutral area with everything else being in one of the bases.

Comment: Incidentally, symmetric TF2 maps tend to be coded by both color (red/orange for RED base, blue/grey for BLU base, white/nature for neutral) and style (central is neutral, base closer to center is cover operations, base end is spytech/secret base).  Sometimes the color is only a highlight (i.e. concrete walls with a large red stripe at the bottom).

Comment: Non-symmetric maps seem to be primarily designed to look like RED bases, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is going to be difficult... but you're going to need a team to do this.

Chances are you'll need at least:

1. 1+ uber Medic.
2. 1+ stickylauncher DemoMen as the Medics' patient(s).  i.e. one that isn't a DemoKnight or Stickyjumper
3. A non-YER, non-DR Spy (this is optional, but may make it easier).  Red-Tape Recorder is recommended.
4. Other damage classes (Soldier, DemoMan, Heavy)
5. A Bonk Scout can also help to distract the sentries.

Now, the trick here is to use the Uber and get the sentries firing on the DemoMan.  Meanwhile, the Spy (if you have one) should be creating a distraction by some of the farther away sentries.  If possible, the Spy should concentrate on the sentry guns whose Engineers are using Wranglers.

The ubered player should be a DemoMan thanks to the Rescue Ranger... Demo is the only class whose damage can be done in burst so that the shoot to heal effect is useless (although if they pick up the gun to move it, two stickies will kill the Engineer)

The Spy's job (if you have one) is two-fold:

1. Sap the sentries and supporting buildings.  Especially the Wrangled sentries as you can't wrangle / remotely heal sapped sentries.
2. Cause a distraction for the Engies to deal with.

The other damage classes should be assisting to take out the sentries while they are distracted by the Uber.  As long as the Ubered players are closer to the sentries, the sentries will fire upon them instead.  The exception is for wrangled sentries (this is one of the reasons the Wrangler is a bit OP).

Now, the biggest problem with the above scenario is if one of the players is using a Short Circuit.

### The Best Solution

Team Scramble.  If teams are unbalanced enough that one team can build 5 sentries out in mid, a scramble is more than warranted.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks! Why no to YER, though? Surely, if there's going to be a Spy taking down sentries and their Engies, he should be able to quickly transform after a backstab (or do the sentries see me transform into my victim and shoot?)?

Comment: I once found myself in an odd situation in which I sapped several sentries using the kunai (not something I use often). I stabbed an engineer, hid behind his dispencer (that gave me cover from the horde of sentries and shotgun blasts), then I shot the engineers to death (after sapping their ONE teleporter), then sapped all of their buildings. That is probably the only time that the kunai let me do anything that the default knife could not (tank all of the shotgun blasts until I was behind cover). Also, it may pay to add snipers, a machina does wonders on sentries.

Comment: @alexqwx The problem with the YER is that you need to get a first backstab kill to disguise.  Which is difficult when the enemy controls the entire central area.  If you CAN get a disguise, then yes, it might be useful as you can backstab Engies without losing your disguise (and thus not being fired on).

Comment: @Powerlord I find that using YER is often a better strategy than any other knife. I pretty much use the cloak and dagger, l'etranger, sapper and YER as my default loadout. I used to use the spycicle and the dead ringer but I found YER to be far superior.

Comment: Your list is a little overkill. An ubercharge and a couple damage classes will be more than enough if all the sentries are tightly clustered. Demo will get more damage out but is susceptible to short circuiting. Heavy gets around short circuit but can have trouble closing the gap.

Comment: @AustinMohr The assumption was that they aren't clustered.  After all, ctf_turbine has multiple entrances to mid.